# jquery ui popup a YouTube Video modally

Tags: jquery-ui, youtube, modal-dialog

Is there a way to use jQueryUI to popup a YouTube video modally?

Here's the YouTube code I have:

```
<object width="480" height="385"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/DIuXtsaUDmM?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/DIuXtsaUDmM?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="480" height="385"></embed></object>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try modifying this code below to fit your scenario .. i've used  your video link though.
You'll have to download the jquery files as well.

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Youtube Popup</title>
<link type="text/css" href="jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script language="javascript" src="jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.min.js"></script>


<script>
    function Show() {

        $( "#dialog:ui-dialog" ).dialog( "destroy" );

        $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({
            height: 470,
                        width: 550,
            modal: true
        });
    }
    </script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="dialog-modal" Title="Youtube Video" style="display:none">

<object width="480" height="385"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/DIuXtsaUDmM?

fs=1&amp;hl=en_US"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" 

value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/DIuXtsaUDmM?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US" type="application/x-

shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="480" height="385"></embed></object>

</div>

<input type="button" onclick="javascript:Show()" value="click me" />

</body>

</html>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I've tried it. It works. Once.  When I close my dialog I can't open the video anymore.  The youtube DIV element is removed from the DOM when I close the modal.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

You could always use [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation) script to embed the flash object into the modal popup.

Use the dialog's open event to attach a handler which embeds the flash movie:

```
$( ".selector" ).bind( "dialogopen", function(event, ui) {
    // use swfobject to include flash movie to
    // container within diaglog
});
```