# Video Embede code in Div panel? In Asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

In Web application, i am using datalist control to bind the Embed videos to a `<div>` dynamically. They are coming good, but when we click on video in the `datalist` they are **start to play**. I dont want that, I would like to play the particular video in a popup, and make a non action on that video [div which contain embeded video]. I want to make that div enable `false`.

```
<asp:DataList ID="DtlstVideos" ToolTip="Click On Video Title" CellPadding="5" CellSpacing="5" runat="server" RepeatColumns="5" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"  OnItemCommandXSSCleaned="DtlstVideos_ItemCommand">
  <ItemStyle />
  <ItemTemplate>
    <div id="divVideos" runat="server"><%# Eval("photos") %></div>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkVide" CommandName="Click" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("videotitle") %>' ToolTip="Play" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id") %>' Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="Blue"></asp:LinkButton>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

This is the current code, when a user clicks on the `LinkButton` a popup will fire and the video will play, but when click on div the video is playing in `datalist` only, is there any solution?

[image]

Comment: have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532210/jquery-ui-popup-a-youtube-video-modally

Comment: where is your code ? what type of video ? youtube or other... code code code please.

Comment: yes it is youtube videos Mr. Aristos. i am placing my code

Answer (score 1):

Id am not sure if I did understand you correct but I hope this might help.

If you are using youtub, you'll be able to access a preview picture of the movi in different-sizes.

The image is accessble via a certain convention like this:

```
 http://img.youtube.com/vi/VIDEO_ID/#.jpg
```

Find details here: http://www.reelseo.com/youtube-thumbnail-image/

So what I would do is display only the image in the datalist (maybe with some div overlay which looks like a player)... and then on click pass the movi ID to your popup and then embed and play the movie in that popup...div or new window whatever you want..

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Well, I would not use that `<div>` as you are using rather I would make use of the `ImageButton` that will act as the video image as when clicking you can fire your `command` and hooking up a javascript event on it you can fire up the popup when you want.

Let's imagine that you can use jQuery with this:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DtlstVideos" ToolTip="Click On Video Title" CellPadding="5" CellSpacing="5" runat="server" RepeatColumns="5" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"  OnItemCommandXSSCleaned="DtlstVideos_ItemCommand">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:ImageButton id="divVideos" CssClass="img-video" runat="server" CommandArgument="<%# Eval("id") %>" data-video-id="<%# Eval("id") %>" CommandName="Click" ImageUrl="<%# Eval("photos") %>" />
    <%# Eval("videotitle") %>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

and with jQuery you can simply hook up the click event to fire up your pop up and your command

```
$(function() {
  $(".img-video").on("click", function() {
    var url = 'playVideo.aspx?id=' + $(this).attr("data-video-id");
    window.open(url, "Video Player","menubar=0,resizable=0,width=650,height=450");
    return true; // let the image button fire the command argument
  });
});
```

But I would never let it fire the `Command` event here and I would hook up always in the `playVideo.aspx` page as there you do have the video `id` as well and you can do what you need in that page without needing to fire the command event on the video strip.

Comment: i will place image button and let you know mr. balexandre thank you for response

Comment: Mr.Balexandre here Photo means not image it is video embede is it works?

Comment: best way is not to embed the video there... just show a video frame image, just like Youtube does when you set the video not to be able to be showed outsite youtube domain. Then in `playVideo.aspx` page you will embed it, and you will only have this page to modify when enbed code change, plus you can do your video play tracker there as well.

Comment: How, can you tell me clearly, how to place the embed video as image

Comment: That's nothing to do with this question. You should add a new question for that and accept any of this answers if they helped you accomplish anything...