# Doing an on click event on iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, youtube

Here is my html code

```
<table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" align="right">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="left" colspan="3">
                <h1>
                    Featured</h1>
            </td>
            <td align="right">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <h1>
                                Popular</h1>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <h1>
                                |
                            </h1>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <h1>
                                Recent</h1>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">
                <iframe width="300" height="400" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/oNgMIrNs1-o" frameborder="0"
                    onload="Show();" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </td>
            <td style="padding-top: 0px;">
                <iframe width="200" height="190" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/oNgMIrNs1-o" frameborder="0"
                    allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </td>
            <td style="padding-top: 0px;">
                <iframe width="200" height="190" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/oNgMIrNs1-o" frameborder="0"
                    allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </td>
            <td style="padding-top: 0px;">
                <iframe width="200" height="190" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/oNgMIrNs1-o" frameborder="0"
                    allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-bottom: 0px;">
                <iframe width="200" height="190" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/oNgMIrNs1-o" frameborder="0"
                    allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </td>
            <td style="padding-top: 0px;">
                <iframe width="200" height="190" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/oNgMIrNs1-o" frameborder="0"
                    allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </td>
            <td style="padding-top: 0px;">
                <iframe width="200" height="190" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/oNgMIrNs1-o" frameborder="0"
                    allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Its a kind of a small gallery.What i'm trying to achieve is on clicking any small videos on right hand side, it must
load in the featured video box.
How to achieve this??

Here is jsfiddle link  http://jsfiddle.net/4HQc4/9/

Comment: use thumbnail images for videos on right instead of loading all videos in iframe.

Comment: ok...dat seems good.let me try

Comment: you could try use something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532210/jquery-ui-popup-a-youtube-video-modally

Comment: @iBlue - take a look at my implementation, it should solve your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this instead: http://jsfiddle.net/4HQc4/10/

JS:

```
$(document).on('click', 'td img', function () {
    var videoID = $(this).data('video');
    $('.featured-box iframe').fadeOut(function () {
        $(this).attr('src', 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + videoID).load(function () {
            $(this).fadeIn();
        });
    });
});
```

HTML change:

```
<td style="padding-top: 0px;">
    <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/oNgMIrNs1-o/mqdefault.jpg" data-video="oNgMIrNs1-o" />
</td>
```

This uses the video preview images and loads the new video in the featured div when they're clicked.